# UIBarButtonItem causes app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, crash-reports, viewwilldisappear

I'm learning to code in Objective-C by developing a simple app.
I'm using a `UISplitViewController` which has `UIBarButtonItem`. 
When you tap an item on the left `UINavigationController`, shows up on the right one.
This right one has a button inside which takes you to a web site, controlled by a browser controller; when tapped, up left on the UIBar appears a button to go back/to the previous view.

The problem is that when I tap this button, the app crashes and Xcode tells me the problem is the method `viewWillDisappear` in the browser controller.
I've checked it up and down dozen times and can't find the error.

[image: code & error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
[self viewWillDisappear : animated];
```

to

```
[super viewWillDisappear : animated];
```

Your way creates an infinite recursion - method calling itself - visible also in Thread 1 call stack.

Comment: Help says not to say thanks, but thanks a lot. I was going crazy.